After a UFO encounter or a UFO sighting, what is the standard procedure? How does one document or report it?
How many astronauts have reported an alien encounter of some kind?
From this question I saw that there's a few astronauts who have told about seeing a UFO of ET origin.
In the selected answer there's 4 astronauts mentioned and the answer is citing space.com, documentaries, autobiographies, mission transcripts and books.
If they see some UFO (whatever origin ET or not) is there nothing they should do to let anyone know? Or just remember it and tell to the concerned people?
Is there any procedure involving documentation of this? Because if it poses danger to the spacecraft in any way, it would probably be better to take note of it somehow except verbally.
Gist of my question: Astronaut sees thing they don't know but is flying near them, what do they do?

Please note that none of those sightings took place on a space mission, but instead while flying in airplanes. Also all were prior to 1965. Based on this a procedure for in space sightings is not necessary. If you are asking about airplane procedures it's off topic here.

@OrganicMarble, yeah I saw that.. I've also seen the Aviation SE question similar to this https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/5011/have-pilots-encountered-a-ufo-and-what-to-do-if-you-have

The question as written seems off topic. Things that astronauts see or do while they are not in space or not doing anything related to space travel is not a Space Exploration topic. More on topic would be to ask what is the procedure for astronauts to report sightings of unidentified objects that are made while they are in space .

@StevePemberton on the last line I've written "danger to the craft". My question is about what they should do if they see some unidentified object flying around while in space.

They should call the ground and tell them just like they do for anything else. No special procedure exists or needs to.

AadirajAnil - changing it to "spacecraft" might make it more clear. Either that or remove the references to things astronauts saw during their pre-astronaut career since it doesn't seem relevant. Other than the Frank Borman conversation with Capcom during Gemini. There are other similar examples such as John Glenn reporting seeing fireflies around his spacecraft during his Mercury flight. I would assume you would also include sightings which were later explained, since your interest seems to be in what procedures they follow when seeing something that they cannot immediately identify.

@StevePemberton, thanks, done.

@OrganicMarble, hmm, understood.

Unless they get close enough for long enough to look in the windows and see ET waving back at them, I'd like to believe that professional astronauts will simply report seeing the object and, that they would withhold any judgement as to its origin.

I’m voting to close this question because UFOs?  Really?  sigh
